# objectAtIndex in NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary

I am trying to create UITableView from my NSDictionary, but how can I use objectForKey? Convert to NSArray?
I need help.
My dictionary looks like:
**

```
{
    "allow_comments" = 1;
    category = 1024194;
    "created_at" = "2011-11-17T01:44";
    forum = 1005401;
    "forum_obj" =     {
        "created_at" = "2011-09-03 03:04:43.514514";
        description = "";
        id = 1005401;
        name = smartfiction;
        shortname = smartfiction;
    };
    hidden = 0;
    id = 474530565;
    identifier =     (
        "2507 http://smartfiction.ru/?p=2507"
    );
    "num_comments" = 2;
    slug = "thread_9714";
    title = "\U041e\U0440\U0438\U0444\U043b\U0430\U043c\U043c\U0430. \U042d\U0436\U0435\U043d \U0418\U043e\U043d\U0435\U0441\U043a\U043e";
    url = "http://smartfiction.ru/prose/oriflamma/";
}
2011-11-19 10:21:25.992 ARSSReader[3067:15503] id 474530565
2011-11-19 10:21:26.864 ARSSReader[3067:15503] Ответ #2: (
        {
        author =         {
            avatar =             {
                cache = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=af6c6f08e213427ad611b00589db00f9&size=32&default=http://mediacdn.disqus.com/1321567697/images/noavatar32.png";
                permalink = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=af6c6f08e213427ad611b00589db00f9&size=32&default=http://mediacdn.disqus.com/1321567697/images/noavatar32.png";
            };
            emailHash = af6c6f08e213427ad611b00589db00f9;
            isAnonymous = 1;
            name = "S Shv";
            profileUrl = "http://disqus.com/guest/af6c6f08e213427ad611b00589db00f9/";
            url = "";
        };
        createdAt = "2011-11-17T22:39:36";
        dislikes = 0;
        forum = smartfiction;
        id = 367003621;
        isApproved = 1;
        isDeleted = 0;
        isEdited = 0;
        isFlagged = 0;
        isHighlighted = 0;
        isJuliaFlagged = 1;
        isSpam = 0;
        likes = 0;
        media =         (
        );
        message = "\U043f\U043e\U0440\U0430\U0437\U0438\U043b\U043e )";
        parent = "<null>";
        points = 0;
        "raw_message" = "\U043f\U043e\U0440\U0430\U0437\U0438\U043b\U043e )";
        thread = 474530565;
    },
        {
        author =         {
            avatar =             {
                cache = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=c1c53088e04a60aab74cd1f149117e69&size=32&default=http://mediacdn.disqus.com/1321567697/images/noavatar32.png";
                permalink = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=c1c53088e04a60aab74cd1f149117e69&size=32&default=http://mediacdn.disqus.com/1321567697/images/noavatar32.png";
            };
            emailHash = c1c53088e04a60aab74cd1f149117e69;
            isAnonymous = 1;
            name = "3,14";
            profileUrl = "http://disqus.com/guest/c1c53088e04a60aab74cd1f149117e69/";
            url = "";
        };
        createdAt = "2011-11-17T02:52:46";
        dislikes = 0;
        forum = smartfiction;
        id = 365544459;
        isApproved = 1;
        isDeleted = 0;
        isEdited = 0;
        isFlagged = 0;
        isHighlighted = 0;
        isJuliaFlagged = 1;
        isSpam = 0;
        likes = 1;
        media =         (
        );
        message = "\U0427\U0438\U0442\U0430\U0442\U044c \U043d\U0430 \U043d\U043e\U0447\U044c \U043f\U0440\U043e\U043a\U0440\U0430\U0441\U0442\U0438\U043d\U0430\U0442\U043e\U0440\U0430\U043c. \U0412\U043f\U0440\U043e\U0447\U0435\U043c, \U043b\U0443\U0447\U0448\U0435 \U0443\U0442\U0440\U043e\U043c.";
        parent = "<null>";
        points = 1;
        "raw_message" = "\U0427\U0438\U0442\U0430\U0442\U044c \U043d\U0430 \U043d\U043e\U0447\U044c \U043f\U0440\U043e\U043a\U0440\U0430\U0441\U0442\U0438\U043d\U0430\U0442\U043e\U0440\U0430\U043c. \U0412\U043f\U0440\U043e\U0447\U0435\U043c, \U043b\U0443\U0447\U0448\U0435 \U0443\U0442\U0440\U043e\U043c.";
        thread = 474530565;
    }
)
```

**
It is comments from disqus.com. I want to create dictionaries for all comments and use them to create UITableView cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing the comments from disqus.com in a dictionary, store each comment in an entry inside an array (it looks like each comment has a block of text you can encapsulate into an object which you can store into an array).

Dictionaries are good for associating values with keys.

Arrays are great for storing lists of objects, much like a list of comments from a disqus site.